# CSS list into a scrolling div - How to autofocus on selected/active <li>?

Tags: css, focus, html-lists, selecteditem

I have a list contained into a scrolling div with fixed height. When I go to the selected page clicking on a category, I want the user to see the current selected category auto focused at its position. that is, the user has not to see the list from the beginning, but focused on the current position. How to do it?

Comment: Some code will be a good starting point.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh updated the question with some code ;-)

Comment: And what HTML does that script produce?

Comment: @DavidThomas what do you mean? it produces an unordered list with categories and subcategories...I need the position focus on the selected category to the next page, when the user does click on that...

Comment: What you've posted as 'the list' is template that creates the list, it's not the list as rendered by the templating script. I know it *produces a list*, but I don't know what the HTML of that list is going to be, which is relevant to your question. Help *us* to help *you*. Ideally post a simple demo to reproduce your problem on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar.

Comment: no, maybe easy without the demo... put in mind the 2 selectors: div.block (or #categories_block_left) as container AND the #categories_block_left ul.tree a.selected for the current position ... how to scroll from the first to the last with jquery? thanks

Comment: i have jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js and jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js already loaded.. can you help?